# prove to have at least one real root by Rolle's theorem

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=x^4+x^3-x-1$. Use Rolle's theorem to prove $4x^3+3x^2-1=0$ has at least one real root in [-1,1].

Do I have to let $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and continue to do it? I have no idea how to use the Rolle's theorem as this can be easily mixed up with LaGrange theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$f(x)=x^4+x^3-x-1$$
$$f(1)=0$$
$$f(-1)=0$$

Since we have $f(1)=f(-1)=0$

Then Using [Rolle's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle's_theorem)

We can say that $\exists c\in[-1,1]$ such that

$$f'(c)=0$$
$$\implies f'(x)=g(x)=4x^3+3x^2-1 $$ has atleast one real root in $[-1,1]$